# Why [float.MaxValue == float.MaxValue + 1] does return true?

Tags: c#, floating-point, overflow

I wonder if you could explain the Overflow in floating-point types.

```
float.MaxValue == float.MaxValue + 1 // returns true
```

Comment: Same reason why infinity+1 is still infinity I'd guess..

Comment: @Blindy: no. More like tears in a tsunami.

Comment: I think it's important to point out (because I haven't seen it in any answer so far) that the precision of a float (or double or decimal) is dependent upon the value itself and the "7 digits of precision" is just a heuristic for relatively small values. A float is very precise close to 0, for instance. On the other hand, a double (say IEEE-754, 64-bit) can only represent all the integers to about ~2^53, which is far smaller than it's entire range.

Comment: @pst: It's 7 significant digits.  Relative precision.  The absolute precision is, as you say, dependent on the value (specifically the exponent) and this is true of scientific notation in general.

Comment: @Ben Voight That was worded wrong on my part: "7 digits after the decimal", while not strictly true, is what I should have written; it was to reinforce why one needs a "larger 1" to make a change to larger float values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because the `1` is way too small to make a dent in the `float.MaxValue` value.

Anything less than 1e32 will fall below the precision of the float, so it's in effect the same as adding a zero.

#### Edit:

ulrichb showed that a value of 1e23 does actually affect float.MaxValue, which has to mean that you are not comparing floats at all, but doubles. The compiler converts all values to doubles before adding and comparing.

Comment: but what if you add 1 really really fast and often? :)

Comment: @kenny & Blindy: Even adding extremely large values of 1 incredibly often, still doesn't reach 1e32. You could probably not get higher than about 1e12. :)

Comment: You'd probably need a better 1.

Answer (score 9):

That's very interesting:

```
float fMax = float.MaxValue;
double dMax = double.MaxValue;

Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", fMax == fMax + 1E22f, fMax + 1E22f);
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", fMax == fMax + 1E23f, fMax + 1E23f);

Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", dMax == dMax + 1E291d, dMax + 1E291d);
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", dMax == dMax + 1E292d, dMax + 1E292d);
```

prints:

```
True, 3.402823E+38
False, 3.402823E+38
True, 1.79769313486232E+308
False, Infinity
```

So, ... as Guffa noted `fMax + 1E23f` is converted to double and `dMax + 1E292d` adds up to `Infinity`.

Comment: Interresting... The result has a lot more significant digits that a float can hold, so the conclusion has to be that the compiler converts all the float values to double before addition and comparing.

Comment: @Guffa: wouldn't surprise me. I've seen release-only bugs in C++ apps caused by the compiler keeping all intermediate results in the 80-bit FPU registers.

Comment: @Guffa: I don't think so, because the same holds for `double` (edited answer).

Comment: If you check the difference between the max value and the threshold, you see that it's about the same for the float and double operations above. That supports the conclusion that the float operations are done using doubles.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is floating point precision. `float.MaxValue` corresponds to 3.40282e+038f. But a `float` has much less precision that, in fact, there are only 7 digits of precision.

Anything beyond that precision is "filled with zeros", and adding 1 to that high number will not change it.

Comment: Hmm... It's not "filled with zeros" any more than 1.3x10³ is "filled with zeros". There's just no way to represent the result of the addition in the datatype being used.

Answer (score 3):

Succinctly, the difference is in the 39th digit, and `float` only stores the first 7 (ish).  This is a characteristic of floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

To get a float type temporary variable to actually hold a single precision value, it must have been loaded from a float variable in memory.  The compiler is generally allowed to represent single-precision values with more precision than required, and tends to do so while the value is in a register.  When it spills back to memory the extra precision is lost.