# Why is double.MaxValue + double.Epsilon not double.Infinity?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, double, .net-4.5

I was going through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32004275/217757) and could not answer one thing. May be, because I have a mathematician's mind, so please forgive me if it is too simple question.

Why is this not resulting in Infinity.

```
double.MaxValue + double.Epsilon
```

However small value Epsilon have, whenever it is added to max value, it should increase the max value by a small precision. Why is that not increased in this case?

Here is the [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BthTBF) where I have been experimenting.

Comment: Not an answer: you do realize that to change value of `double` near MaxValue you need to modify it be really large (random guess 10^10?) increment, don't you? Or maybe it is an answer... [Double.PositiveInfinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.positiveinfinity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returned when value is greater than MaxValue, but adding such small increment not going to change it at all.

Comment: Here is another answer which can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251298/why-float-maxvalue-float-maxvalue-1-does-return-true

Comment: @mybirthname I think it is perfect duplicate... (and my guess of increment was *a bit* off - you need to add `1E292d` :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default to-nearest rounding mode, the mathematical result of the addition would have to be above the middle point between `double.MaxValue` and the next floating-point value that could be represented if the exponent range was wider for the floating-point result to round up to Infinity.

Operations resulting in a mathematical result between `double.MaxValue` and this middle point are rounded down to `double.MaxValue`.

`double.Epsilon` is much smaller than the distance between `double.MaxValue` and this middle point, therefore the result of the floating-point addition is `double.MaxValue`.

This phenomenon is called “absorption” in general (not only when one of the summands is `double.MaxValue`, but as soon as the ratio between the summands is such that the result is the same as the largest summand).

Comment: Out of curiosity, I was testing for the limit before the value hits infinity. I found, consequently, that `var i = double.MaxValue - 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0; (i == double.MaxValue).Dump();` returns `true`. My first tests were subtracting 1, and I figured it was due to precision. But how can this be..?

Comment: @Rob I think [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251298/why-float-maxvalue-float-maxvalue-1-does-return-true) found by mybirthname explains it too.

Comment: @Rob `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0` (about 70 zeroes) is **much** smaller than `double.MaxValue ` (~1e308) and even than the difference between `double.MaxValue ` and the next representable floating-point number if the exponent range was wider (take out about 16 zeroes, resulting in a number that must be around 1e292, give or take a factor of 100).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Thanks to you both, that makes sense now :)

Comment: @Rob Adding anything less than 179769313486231580793728971405303415079934132710037826936173778980444968292764750946649017977587207096330286416692887910946555547851940402630657488671505820681908902000708383676273854845817711531764475730270069855571366959622842914819860834936475292719074168444365510704342711559699508093042880177904174497792 will result in DBL_MAX. (That's 1/2 ULP above DBL_MAX)

Comment: @Rob ...or subtracting as per your example.